# Seeking jQuery-based transition library

Tags: jquery, jquery-easing

I'm looking for a library (or plugin) that help me create a slideshow where (besides the simple ordering of images) I'm able to define the beginning and ending positions (either X/Y, or Zooms) for a given image and the plugin animates the intervening steps between them.

Flash has a number of tools/libs like this, i'm sure jQuery has seen similar. Ideally something that offers a range of easing effects as well. I understand these elements are native to jQuery...i'm looking for a time-tested wrapper.

thx

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [jQuery Slide](http://www.wbotelhos.com/slidy/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: The link is to 'Slidy' - i'm not seeing support for movement, zooming, or easing (beyond rate of fade). Am i missing some advanced features/demos?